# Understanding terms of Black Scholes Equation

Tags: partial-derivative, stochastic-calculus, finance

I want to know how the derivative of $C(S,t)$ with respect to t is calculated (theta). A lot of sources just mention "with a bit of manipulation.." but I have been unsuccessful in understanding this manipulation.

Similarly, I am trying to understand how $\frac{\partial^{2} C }{\partial S^{2}} = \frac{N(d1)}{S\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}$

Comment: The formula is $N'(d_1)/S\sigma\sqrt{T-t}$ and this is derived from the chain rule.

Comment: @i707107 I get it to the part where $\frac{\partial^{2}C}{\partial S^{2}} = N'(d1) * \frac{\partial d1}{\partial S}$. However I fail to see how to take the derivative of d1 with respect to S ($\frac{\partial d1}{\partial S}$).

Answer (score 1):

From the formula, 
$$
d_1= \frac{ \ln(S/K) + (r-\delta+\frac12 \sigma^2)(T-t)}{\sigma \sqrt{T-t}},
$$
we have 
$$
\frac{\partial d_1}{\partial S} = \frac1{S\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}.$$
This is because $S$ is only included in $\ln(S/K)$ and the derivative of it with respect to $S$ is $1/S$. Also, note that there is $\sigma \sqrt{T-t}$ term on the denominator.